# How to exchange pointer then free old pointer like RCU

Tags: c

I have many reader threads reading cache data, e.g.

```
struct {
   hash_table *cache;
   int64_t version;
} ctx;
```

Many reader threads reading the cache, e.g.

```
void *get_from_cache(void *key)
{
    /* Maybe access invalid address when writer thread free it too quickly ! */
    /* I can use setjmp/longjmp to deal the exception, but it's too expensive ! */
    /* On Windows, I can use SEH, but how about Linux ? */

    /* Finally, can I avoid it with zero cost on reader thread ? */

    return cache.get(key);
}
```

Only one writer thread update the cache:

```
void update_cache()
{
    int64_t new_version = get_current_version();

    if (new_version > ctx.version) {
        hash_table *new_cache = load_cache();
        hash_table *old_cache = ctx.cache;

        ctx.version = new_version;
        ctx.cache = new_cache;

        /* How to determine the wait time is enough ? */
        /* Just use a experiential value ? */
        wait_some_time();

        free_hash_table(old_cache);
    }
}
```

Thanks for some help.

Comment: You appear to be attempting to synchronize by using timed waits. That doesn't work. You also appear to be contemplating trying to detect and recover from accessing freed memory. Again that cannot work. But I've no real idea what you are actually trying to achieve. In my view you need to explain your goals in the question.

Comment: Just like rcu_xchg_pointer and call_rcu : http://linuxplumbersconf.org/2009/slides/Mathieu-Desnoyers-talk-lpc2009.pdf

Comment: If that's what you want to do, do it. Why show us bizarre code where you contemplate timed waits and recovering from invalid memory access.

Comment: Is what you want an atomic pointer exchange? Like the Windows InterlockedExchangePointer? It would help if you could define precisely what you want. And not in comments, but in the question. Also, C has no functionality for this, you need to specify platform and threading framework.

Comment: Because URCU does not support Windows, I want some help of implement it on Windows platform.

Comment: You need to re-write your question to say exactly that. That's a good question. Please take time over this and make a good question.

Answer (score 0):

From the title it seems you are attempting to rely on the atomic nature of pointer operations.
please take a look at [Is changing a pointer considered an atomic action in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879077/is-changing-a-pointer-considered-an-atomic-action-in-c).

also - trying to detect invalid memory access is really bad. what if you get a pointer to a valid, but incorrect, address.

I would go with more conventional synchronization mechanisms.

Comment: Here is my idea come from: http://linuxplumbersconf.org/2009/slides/Mathieu-Desnoyers-talk-lpc2009.pdf void replace_data(struct mystruct data)
{
struct mystruct *new, *old;
new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
memcpy(new, &data, sizeof(*new));
old = rcu_xchg_pointer(&rcudata, new);
call_rcu(free, old);
}

Comment: "I do not care about reader thread got old cached data." Surely you'll care when the reader thread accesses memory that has been freed.

Comment: ok. I can see where you are going and I think it is a valid direction. I think you should look into interlocked conditional exchange / interlocked increment. Also google "optimistic locking c++" for something related.