# Is there a platform without native pointer sized atomics but with other sized atomics?

Tags: c++, multithreading, rust, cpu-architecture, atomic

I am doing a refactoring of widely used open source library and want to make it as robust as possible.

Currently, it uses atomic `size_t` variables if it is supported but I wonder if it can miss some obscure platform which has, for example, 32 bit atomics while having 64 bit pointers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/879090/11683?

Comment: Do you have any idea what platforms this might be used on?  Sometimes, one has to limit one's scope.  And what library is it, I think you should add that to your question.  Of course, an additional level of indirection can fix anything, so why not make the type of your atomics a `typedef` and leave it at that for now?

Comment: @GSerg: That answer is saying that plain `size_t` and `void*` aren't atomic.  Of course not, regardless of underlying hardware.  [Which types on a 64-bit computer are naturally atomic in gnu C and gnu C++? -- meaning they have atomic reads, and atomic writes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71866535) (none).  This question is asking whether `std::atomic<size_t>` and `std::atomic<int *>` are both equally likely to be `::is_always_lock_free`.

Comment: In the [Rust doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/index.html) about atomics there is a note saying "`AtomicUsize` and `AtomicIsize` are generally the most portable", and also a few atomics that are not available in some systems...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure all modern mainstream systems have lock-free pointer-width atomics, at least ones that run OSes like Linux.

8-bit platforms like AVR can mostly only load/store bytes, but pointers are 16 or 24 bit, so `size_t` wouldn't be lock-free either.  (But AVR systems are single-core, and even for single bytes you only get RMW atomicity by disabling interrupts.)

Only a segmented memory model or something would have pointers wider than `size_t`.  Flat memory models are nearly universal, where `size_t` and `uintptr_t` are the same size, and same width as pointers.

---

Many ISAs have lock-free atomic RMW for 2x pointer width, but not always efficient pure-load or pure-store for that width.  (For example, x86-64 without AVX for the recently-documented guarantee of 128-bit atomicity only has `lock cmpxchg16b`, which can be "abused" for pure load and pure store.  But that dirties the cache line, and even faults on read-only memory.  Which is party of why GCC since 7 doesn't inline 16-byte atomic load, store, or RMW, even with `-mcx16`.)

---

The Rust docs (https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/atomic/index.html) discuss some older platforms like armv5te apparently only had atomic load/store, not atomic RMW like CAS or even swap/exchange.  That required OS support, presumably disabling interrupts on a single-core CPU/MCU.  Similarly for "thumbv6m".  But that's a problem for `AtomicUsize` as well as `AtomicPtr`.

Comment: One issue with `size_t` atomics for me is that, as long as Linux doesn't have pervasive support for the `futex2` system call, all non-int-sized atomics are second-class citizens since `std::atomic::wait()` does not directly translate into a system call

Comment: [CHERI](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/security/ctsrd/cheri/) is a new architecture extension with 128-bit tagged pointers and 64-bit integers.  Pointers can only be created from other valid pointers, which prevents certain types of attacks.  I cannot speak to its atomics support, though.

Comment: @bk2204: Interesting.  Baseline RISC-V doesn't have double-width atomics, at least it didn't in 2020 when a thread on https://lists.riscv.org/g/tech/topic/requirements_for_128_bit/76126473 discussed adding it.  Neither with LR/SC nor with single-instruction atomic-modify-operate (like `amoswap.d.aqrl` in https://godbolt.org/z/PPh45qGx5 for `.exchange` on `std::atomic<long>` on RV64).  But hopefully CHERI changes that because single atomically updating pointers is crucial for many algorithms.